# Understanding the treatment of NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In the Pandas documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#sum-prod-of-empties-nans, it is written thus:

> The descriptive statistics and computational methods discussed in the data structure overview (and listed here and here) are all written to account for missing data. For example:
>
> When summing data, NA (missing) values will be treated as zero.
>
> If the data are all NA, the result will be 0.

if this is the case, why, for instance, do I get the following outcome?:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
>>> s1 = pd.Series([3,np.nan])
>>> s2 = pd.Series([np.nan,2])
>>> s1 + s2
0 NaN
1 NaN
```

According to the documentation, I would have thought (and hoped) it would produce:

```
0 3
1 2
```

I realize I can use s1.fillna(0) and s2.fillna(0) to achieve the latter outcome, but what am I missing in the Pandas documentation about the way NaNs are treated?

Comment: What do you get for `s1.sum()`? How about for `np.nan + 3`?

Comment: The section you quoted is talking about functions that process the series. It doesn't apply when just doing ordinary arithmetic.

Comment: [Series.sum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)  has a `skipna` parameter with a default value of `True`. [Series.add](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html#pandas-series-add) has a `fill_value` parameter that defaults to `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us do `add`

```
s1.add(s2,fill_value=0)
0    3.0
1    2.0
dtype: float64
```